# JavaFX TableView Unable to scroll Horizontally

Tags: javafx, horizontal-scrolling

I have a JavaFx program which populates tableview with values. The table should display only 6 columns and the rest should be visible when scrolled.

But the scroll bar will not move when using mouse/keyboard. The horizontal scroll bar won't move either with mouse or the keyboard arrow keys. The vertical scroll atleast moves only with keyboard arrow keys.

I tried

```
Table.scrollTo(7);
```

It just scrolls down instead of horizontally.
Uploading a screenshot of the image here.
[image: TableView].

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Table.scrollToColumnIndex(7);`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#scrollToColumnIndex-int-).

As for moving through the table with arrow keys. You need to [enable cell selection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/TableSelectionModel.html#cellSelectionEnabledProperty) to allow you to select single cells. Otherwise you only ever select complete rows which doesn't make `TableView` scroll horizontally:

```
Table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Wow it worked but can you also help me how to do it with a mouse-wheel or by dragging the scroll bar with the mouse

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue but i resolved this by smart trick

```
 tableView.addEventFilter(ScrollEvent.SCROLL, (ScrollEvent event) -> {
                    ScrollBar hBar = getScrollBar(tableView, Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
                    if (event.getDeltaY() > 0 && event.isShiftDown()) {
                        if (hBar.getValue() != hBar.getMin()) {
                            hBar.setValue(hBar.getValue() - 20);
                            event.consume();
                        } else {
                            event.consume();
                        }
                    } else if (event.isShiftDown()) {
                        if (hBar.getValue() != hBar.getMax()) {
                            hBar.setValue(hBar.getValue() + 20);
                            event.consume();
                        } else {
                            event.consume();
                        }
                    }

                });
```

This will work and scroll horizontally with shift_key + mouse_scroll.
Hope this will work for you too.. :)